# Android ExpandableListView not showing

Tags: android, layout, expandablelistview

So I have a `ExpandableListView` in my layout, but for some reason It is showing only some part of it when I run the app. Yes, it's "some" part - actually almost the enture first `GroupView`.

If I set a fixed height to the list at `android:layout_height="some dp"`, instead of `android:layout_height="match_parent"` I can see the whole list. But, If I have too many group view's and child view's, again, I can see only some part of it (as the height is fixed).

I've tried to put the expandable list inside a `LinearLayout`, have tried to set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, and so on, but without success.

How can I solve this?

Thank you,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- That's the main layout.-->
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroll_view_m"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- This LinearLayout is here because a ScrollView can only have one child view.-->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- That's the second ScrollView. But this one is horizontal.-->
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/map_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp">

        <!-- This LinearLayout is here because a ScrollView can only have one child view.-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- Some view's here -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_down"
        android:text="Scroll down to see marker info!"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/m_expandable_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: try to put ExpandableListView in single ScrollView. I know you your whole layout have ScrollView as root element but just put another ScrollView for ExpandableListView and try. I think it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have just tried your idea but didn't work...

Comment: Why you need the scrollview?

Comment: Because I'm using a GoogleMap on the activity, and I'd like the user to have a good user experience with a big map. Under the map, I'd show some informations.